# Changing Look and Feel to current windows theme and saving it

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

So i'm making an application and recently switched my windows theme and application looks 10x better. So my question would be how I can set application look and feel to my current windows theme so if anyone would open application would see it?

Comment: Doesn't your windows theme just change the window border color?

Comment: *"how I can set application look and feel to my current windows theme so if anyone would open application would see it?"* Linux/Unix and OS X users would detest seeing a Windows theme on their OS'!  Here, where I run Windows with the video circuitry that came built into the mother board, the PC cannot display those cute 'partially transparent' borders the kids seem to love so much..  I don't think such a look would be portable, even if you did manage to achieve it on one machine.